# Сумма цифр числа

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Подскажите алгоритм нахождения суммы цифр числа (например, восьмизначного).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первое — постоянно берем остаток от деления на 10. Делим на 10, пока наше число не превратится в 0:

```
while (number)
{
    sum += number % 10;
    number /= 10;
}
```

Второе — перевести число в строку и пройтись циклом по всей строке, суммируя при этом цифры:

```
sprintf(str, "%d", number);
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    sum += str[i] - '0';
```

Comment: `i < strlen(str)` - не надо так делать, длина вычисляется каждый раз.